# MYSQL: select from table where a string in a column matches?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select from a table where a column which has a string in it matches some criteria.

the normal way without the string scenario is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename HWERE columnName='something'
```

but lets say the `columnName` contains a value like this:

```
1,2,3,4 | someemail@yahoo.com
```

and we want to select from the table where the *columnName* contains the `someemail@yahoo.com`. So, how would i need to go about this?

I tried something like this but I'm 100% sure I'm doing it wrong:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(columnName,' | ',-1) from tableName
```

because I don't see how the `WHERE` clause come in that statement!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: You're looking for `like` operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnName LIKE '%someemail@yahoo.com%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnName LIKE '%someemail@yahoo.com%';
```